# Printing a simple table in Python

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I have something like this (Python3):

```
for p in something:
  for r in something_else:
    print(r, end=" ")
```

but I want each last print in the inner loop to end with a newline to create a nice table.
Is there some short and elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
for p in something:
  for r in something_else:
    print("%s\t" % r, end=" ")
  print()
```

More elegant might be

```
for p in something:
  print(" ".join(map(str, something_else)))
```

Note that this will just print a table of the elements of something_else a bunch of times. What is in your list? How do you want the table to look? It might help if you're a little more specific in your question.

Comment: You can `map(str, something_else)` if it doesn't just contain strings.

Comment: Well, I need no whitespace (except the newline) after the last item in the row. something_else is a list of ints.

I just need:

1 2 3 4newline
3 4 5 6newline etc.

something_else in in fact a p (I have made an error above) and it is a list of ints. I just now use:

`    i = 0
    for r in p:
        i += 1
        if i < n: print(r, end=" ")
        else: print(r)`

which looks ugly (sorry cannot format the code properly in the comment)

Comment: " ".join(...) is what you are looking for - it places a space (" ") between each item in the passed list, and returns the resulting string. See my answer.